# Plot exponential curves: Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, axis

I would need to draw some curves like this:

[image]

these are curves drawn at different values of a constant parameter $r$. The equation of these curves is

[image]

[image]

the independent variable is `T`.
These curves were plotted for values of $r$ increasing from the top down. `xi` is between `0` and `1`, `T` is between 0 and `\infty`. The asymptotes of any curve for `T` approches to `\infty` is

[image]

This is my attempt, who produces "Dimension too large" error

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ead}{5000};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Eai}{10000};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{8.31};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ad}{30000000};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ai}{70000000};
      \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm, height=6cm,
    xmin=100, xmax=1000,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    axis lines=middle,
    x label style={at={(xticklabel cs:1)}, below},
    y label style={at={(yticklabel cs:1)}, above},
    xlabel={$T$}, ylabel={$\xi$},
    ]              
     \addplot [blue, very thick, samples=100, smooth, ]
     { \Ad*(exp(-\Ead/(\R*x))-0.2) / ( \Ad*(exp(-\Ead/(\R*x))) + \Ai*(exp(-\Eai/(\R*x))) ) };
    \end{axis}
        \draw[-stealth] (8,4) -- ++(0,-2) node[midway,above,anchor=west] {$r$ crescente};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: In the argument of the exponential function there is 1/T, so T cannot go from 0 to infinity.

Comment: The error message says, it tries plotting larger than 19 feet. Suggest doing the following: 1) Verifying your formula and data with a different plot tool, like Excel, Mathematica etc. With samples set up to 40 your code creates just 3 lines, without visible curves. 2) Re-check the formula in `\addplot ` again, e.g. by a collegue. 3) Make use of scaling, e.g. express ` E_{a,x} ` in units/multiples of `RT `. This may make it easier to follow your code .

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `domain` for the plot like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ead}{5000}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Eai}{10000}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{8.31}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ad}{30000000}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ai}{70000000}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm, height=6cm,
xmin=100, xmax=1000,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
axis lines=middle,
x label style={at={(xticklabel cs:1)}, below},
y label style={at={(yticklabel cs:1)}, above},
xlabel={$T$}, ylabel={$\xi$},
]              
\addplot[blue, very thick, domain=100:1000, samples=100, smooth] { \Ad*(exp(-\Ead/(\R*x))-0.2) / ( \Ad*(exp(-\Ead/(\R*x))) + \Ai*(exp(-\Eai/(\R*x))) ) };
\end{axis}
\draw[-stealth] (8,4) -- ++(0,-2) node[midway,above,anchor=west] {$r$ crescente};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]